# Read the JSON array value in the rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have try to getting the params via post method

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 945ce038-4bf1-ed50-afcb-cc715cf3a3fc

{
    "service_requests": [{"service_id":2},{"service_id" : 3}]
}
```

In the controller I have test with a method and print like this. But I could not able to print this. How do I print all the values in for each or for loop from this Json Array of JSON Objects

```
def test
   render :html => params[:service_requests][0].service_id
end
```

Comment: parse json to hash: `JSON.parse(your_json_string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
     render :html => params[:service_requests].map{|s| s["service_id"]}
```